# Передать id кнопки на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть json-файл, на его основе вывожу в браузер значения и возле каждого значения кнопку "Удалить" (c id "delete-user + порядковый номер"). Далее мне нужно этот номер как-то отправить на сервер, чтобы знать, какого юзера удалять.

Так выглядит кнопка, которую генерирую:

```
'<button type="submit" class="button" id="delete-user' + index + '">'
```

Так выглядит функция клика по этой кнопке:

```
$('body').on('click', "button[id^='delete-user']", function() {
    //Получаем из id порядковый номер юзера
     var value = $(this).attr('id').replace('delete-user', '');
    GetDetails(value);
});
```

Так выглядит сам ajax-запрос:

```
function GetDetails(value){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: {test:value}
}).done(function () {
    console.log('success');
}).fail(function () {
    console.log('fail');
});
};
```

Вот PHP-код:

```
if( isset( $_POST['test'] ) )
{
echo 'Кнопка нажата!';
}
```

В итоге в консоль уходит 'success', но echo не всплывает. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: ну правильно, ты его и не выводишь)  `done(function (response) { console.log(response); .......`

Comment: Всё равно не понял:(  responce -- это ответ от сервера, который должен быть? Он обязателен?
Заменил свой код на done(function (response) { console.log(response);  -- в итоге в консоль попала информация о всём коде страницы (где и нашёлся текст "Кнопка нажата!"). Но почему эта информация есть только в консоли? 
И можно ли в PHP-коде уже писать код удаления юзера? Или ещё какие-то махинации нужно сделать?
P.S. Первый раз что-то пробую ajax-ом передавать, прошу прощения за глупые вопросы.

Comment: Да, правильно, `response` - это ответ сервера. Всё, что ты отдашь там на вывод, прилетает в первый параметр колбэк фукнции..... можно ознакомится тут http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-запрос в пункте *Получение данных с сервера*........ что именно прилетит тоже зависит от параметра (dataType), например  json или html..... зависит от параметра dataType в Ajax запросе.......в твоем случае, скорее всего, выводится вся html потому, что надо "убивать" весь остальной вывод после `echo`, например `echo 'Кнопка нажата!'; exit();` .....информация в консоли, потому что я только туда её передал)

Comment: Вместо консоли ты можешь информацию распарсить или вывести в теги html и вообще с ней делать в той функции что угодно, на что фантазии хватит.........`И можно ли в PHP-коде уже писать код удаления юзера` - можно, соблюдая правила безопасности

Comment: `в итоге в консоль попала информация о всём коде страницы` -- Но скорее всего у тебя и html и php находятся в одном файле, поэтому у тебя выводится и то и другое... если ты хочешь получать только ответ от сервера, то отправлять надо запрос на совершенно другую страницу php. в котором будет только он

Comment: Да, всё верно. У меня html и php в одном файле. А можно обойтись вообще без ответа от сервера? Раньше я делал кнопки добавления новых записей (с фиксированным id). Кликаешь на кнопку, отправляется GET-запросы, на PHP в json-файл дозаписываются данные, обнуляются запросы из url. А в js коде новые значения уже автоматически добавлялись на страницу. Сейчас мне нужно сделать то же самое, только не добавить данные, а удалить. Проблема  в том, что id кнопки уже неизвестен, поэтому как-то нужно передать эту информацию на сервер. Но обратно получать я ничего не хочу. Или так не получится?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотри, я б посоветовал сделать так:
HTML/PHP (я так понял у тебя это index.php):

```
<button class="button button-delete-user" data-id="<?=$index?>">
```

JS код:

```
$('body').on('click', "button-delete-user", function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          id = $this.attr('data-id');
      GetDetails(id); // название функции не айс
})

function GetDetails(id) {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax.php",
       data: {action: 'deleteUser', id: id}
     }).done(function (status) {
       console.log(status);
     }).fail(function () {
       console.log('fail');
     });
}
```

тут я рекомендую обработчик вынести в отдельный файл, типа ajax.php со след. содержимым (тут уже как душе угодно):

```
<?
  if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
       if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'deleteUser') {
            // запрос на удаление и проверь наличие $_REQUEST['id']
            echo 'Пользователь удален';
       }
  } else {
      echo 'Нет команды'; // как пример
  }
?>
```

а лучше ответ вообще отдавать json форматом, так ты можешь лучше обработать ответ на js

Если все же хочешь сделать на страницу index.php, то тогда используй след. конструкцию в php:

```
 if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'deleteUser') { // условия сам допиши какие нужны
      ob_clean();
      // все манипуляции с юзером
      echo 'Пользователь удален';
      die();
 }
```

тем самым тебе не будет отдаваться весь контент страницы index.php в ответ на ajax запрос

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, если я использую массив на выходе, правильно ли будет в php: `$qwerty = json_encode(array("total_sum" => 10, "total_quantity" => 3)); die($qwerty);` Затем в JS: `success: function(res){ var result = $.parseJSON(res); $("#uuu").html(result.total_sum); ...}`

Comment: Дмитрий, если не путаю, то сразу можно в js, res.total_sum, так как вы отдаете json с php

Comment: Спасибо! К сожалению, так нельзя, не работает.

Comment: Дмитрий, может в ответе что-то лишнее приходит? Только json_encode передаётся? Выше ничего нет? Хотя парсер бы тоже ругался) как вариант в заголовке ответа отдавать формат json.

Comment: Кстати, может я путаю с $.get и $.post, вроде эти функции автоматом парсят ответ при возможности, а $.ajax более кастомная штука)

Comment: Да, Вы были правы, необходимо передать заголовок, а выводить уже так `alert(res['total_sum']);` Заголовок вывожу в php до `$qwerty = json_encode(array("total_sum" => 10,ю...));` так: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` Только вот не пойму в чем отличие от моего примера выше и вот этого с передачей заголовка без `$.parseJSON`, может подскажите?:)